# What am I doing wrong for this challenge question?

Tags: java

I am doing a challenge on Hackerrank, and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, and neither can my teacher. Every time I submit my code, Test Case 0 (it doesn't tell you what it tests) fails.
Here is the challenge:

```
You are helping search and rescue analyze data from their radar to help locate a boat lost at sea. The problem is due to the water not being flat there are a lot of items that appear on the radar that might be a boat, but are not a boat.

Input Format

The first line of input will provide the number of rows and columns for the radar data. The lines after will provide the radar information.

Sample Input
4 3
w w w
w b b
w w w
w b w
Constraints

The data comes in as a 2D array of characters. Water is labelled with the character 'w' and a possible boat has the label 'b'. Fake boats are easy to identify, because they have another boat next to them. The actual boat will only have water next to it. Everything the radar cannot see (the edges of the 2D array) is assumed to be water. Examples (we don't worry about the diagonals):

  w                    b 
w b w    boat        w b w  fake boat
  w                    w
Output Format

Your program will output the row and column where the boat is located (there is at max one boat) or -1, -1 if there is no boat.

Sample Output
3, 1
Sample Input 0

4 3
w w w
w b b
w w w
w b w
Sample Output 0

3, 1
Sample Input 1

3 6
w w w w w w
w b b w w w
w w w w b b
Sample Output 1

-1, -1
```

And here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean[][] isBoat = new boolean[sc.nextInt()][sc.nextInt()];
        for(int r = 0; r < isBoat.length; r++) {

            //System.out.println();

            for(int c = 0; c < isBoat[0].length; c++) {

                isBoat[r][c] = (sc.next().equals("b") ? true : false);
                //System.out.print(isBoat[r][c] + ", ");

            }

        }
        int boatR = -1, boatC = -1;
        for(int r = 0; r < isBoat.length; r++) {

            //System.out.println();

            for(int c = 0; c < isBoat[0].length; c++) {

                if(isBoat[r][c]) {
                    boolean above = false, below = false, left = false, right = false;
                    if(r != 0 && isBoat[r - 1][c]) {
                        above = true; 
                    }
                    if(r != isBoat.length - 1 && isBoat[r + 1][c]) { 
                        below = true;
                    }
                    if(c != 0 && isBoat[r][c - 1]) { 
                        left = true; 
                    }
                    if(c != isBoat[r].length - 1 && isBoat[r][c + 1]) { 
                        right = true; 
                    }
                    if(!above && !below && !left && !right) {
                        boatR = r;
                        boatC = c;
                    }

                    //System.out.print((boatR == r && boatC == c) + ", ");
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(boatR + ", " + boatC);
    }
}
```

I have tried dozens of randomly generated cases in Eclipse and they have all worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can we have the test case 0 ?

Comment: @Calips It does not tell you what the test case is... It's mentioned in the question...

Comment: also the above code has compilation issues, edit your code

Comment: @Calips it says "we don't worry about the diagonals"

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman Oh ! thanks for the note

Comment: Is there a direct link to the question? Since it fails on #0, it may be some systematic issue or misunderstanding rather than a bug. Perhaps the input is actually `www` but the question's formatting makes it look like `w w w`

Comment: @WhyJava I have updated my code. Thank you for noticing that, fortunately it was just syntax and inconsequential to the issue at hand. My code does pass all other test cases, including the two given as examples. Here is a link to the challenge if anyone would be willing to try it in-editor: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mathcs-day-19-pract-contest/challenges/find-the-missing-boat